# Using tables with RedCloth inserts a lot of extra <br/> before each table

Tags: ruby, textile, redcloth

I am using the tables in [RedCloth](http://redcloth.org/), for example

```
|cat|yeah|what|
|beery|true|fly|
|baru|false|mirror|
```

But I get a lot of `<br/>` and then the table....

What is going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That table doesn't produce any `<br/>`s when formatted using the redcloth.org "try it" box on their homepage. However, something like this:

```
a
|cat|yeah|what|
|beery|true|fly|
|baru|false|mirror|
```

produces:

```
<p>a<br />
|cat|yeah|what|<br />
|beery|true|fly|<br />
|baru|false|mirror|</p>
```

So I would guess that you have a paragraph right before the tables without a blank link separating them. Adding an empty line:

```
a

|cat|yeah|what|
|beery|true|fly|
|baru|false|mirror|
```

Produces what is probably the desired result:

```
<p>a</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cat</td>
        <td>yeah</td>
        <td>what</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>beery</td>
        <td>true</td>
        <td>fly</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>baru</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td>mirror</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```